# How to update k8s pods in another namespace using Jenkins - Minikube

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, minikube

I have created a cluster using minikube which has 2 namespaces, `dev` and `infra`. `dev` contains my UI and backend apps while `infra` contains my Jenkins `StatefulSet`. I set Jenkins and added the Kubernetes plugin (v 1.1.3). Now I want to create a Jenkins job so that I can redeploy services in my `dev` namespace.

However, when my Jenkins job runs, I can see that it spins a new pod in the `infra` namespace as expected for the build, but this pod does not have access to the `kubeconfig` or the `kubectl` command. How do I promote builds in this case?

Here is my [Kubernetes Cloud Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypmmp.png)

And here is the [console output of a sample job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMJql.png)

The sample job above does nothing, I was just testing to make sure that it spins off a pod of its own every time it is run.

How can I use these Jenkins jobs now to redeploy my services/pods in the `dev` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

> this pod does not have access to the kubeconfig or the kubectl command

You need to use a jenkins agent docker image that has those commands

You also need that agent pod to use a service account that has permission to access the `dev` namespace if you want to change things there